# Same object keep different states depending of the thread Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, concurrency

Debugging my application, there is an object (only one) of this class:

```
public class MqttInterface implements MqttPlatformInterfaceObserver{

    private MqttMessage lastMessage;

    ....
    
    public MqttMessage getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;    
    }

    @Override
    public void mqttMessageArrived(String message)  {
        try {
            lastMessage = new JSONParser().parseJsonBodyAs(MqttMessage.class, message);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
    }
        
}
```

The `void mqttMessageArrived(String)` method is implemented using an Observer design pattern, so the object is registered and notified when a new message arrives.

I have two breakpoints (one in each method body) At some point after some time application is running, I get that when `getLasMessage()` message is passed to the object, it is returning a old `lastMessage` object with old state. Although `mqttMessageArrived(String)` is being called later several times the `lastMessage` object returned by `getLastMessage()` method keep being the same and it is never updated .

I check that the `lastMessage` attribute is being updated by `mqttMessageArrived` method (no `Exception` is thrown) and indeed when the program stops in the `mqttMessageArrived` method because the breakpoint, I see `lastMessage` state is being updated, but after that when the program stops in `getLastMessage method()`, it has the same old state.

I dont understand how this behaviour is possible for the same object, I have been thinking it is related with some concurrency or some cache issue.

Comment: Maybe make the cariable `volatile`?

Comment: I think you are running into issues with memory visibility here and using the volatile keyword for lastMessage might help. Some reading on atomic access from oracle here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: Now I know a bit about volatile keyword, I wonder If I have a web app and each request execute in a different thread, if one thread modifies an object state, the thread ends and another thread starts (after the first has ended) and read the get object state, it will get the updated state? I mean, cacheing object state is done when the thread is created, or after the thread has read the object state for first time and for sucessive reads?